# how to show hidden component by js

Tags: javascript, html, css

can't figure out the reason why the code doesn't work.

Html Structure:

```
<p id="myP0" hidden>
  This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
<p>This is a visible paragraph.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The hidden attribute is not supported in IE10 or earlier versions.</p>
<input type="button" onclick="demoDisplay()" value="show">
```

Javascript:

```
function demoDisplay() {
  document.getElementById("myP0").style.display = "visible";
}
```

suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: 'visible' is not a property of 'display', use 'block'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is in your fiddle, you have the JavaScript configured to run `onload`, this is an issue because your `demoDisplay` is now wrapped in an `onload` function and therefore not in the global scope. Anything that you call from an inline `onclick` must be in the global scope. Change the fiddle config to run in the header or body (no wrap).

The second problem is `visible` isn't a possible value of the `display` property. Change this to `block` and your code will work.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3r88cwee/).

```
document.getElementById("myP0").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Why **document.getElementById("myP0").style.visibility = 'visible';** does not work either.